# Run new instance of CMD in PowerShell without a long string of text

Tags: powershell, cmd

So i was wondering if there was a way to remove all of the "&" when you're running an instance of cmd with arguments through PowerShell

For example:

```
start-process cmd -ArgumentList "/C","timeout /t 5 /nobreak & echo hello & timeout /t 5 /nobreak"
```

Turn into something like:

```
start-process cmd -ArgumentList "/C", {
  "timeout /t 5 /nobreak" 
  "echo hello"
  "timeout /t 5 /nobreak"
}
```

Im new so idk

Answer (score 3):

`-ArgumentList` takes a array of strings, and the array subexpression operator (`@(...)`) can span multiple lines:

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList @(
  "/C"
  "timeout /t 5 /nobreak &"
  "echo hello &"
  "timeout /t 5 /nobreak"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **`cmd.exe`'s `/c` and `/k` parameters do not support *multi-line* strings as arguments**, so **in order to submit *multiple commands*, you *must* use `&` to concatenate them on a *single line***.

However, you can let PowerShell do the work for you, which allows you to use a multi-line string on the PowerShell side, as you would write commands in a batch file:

```
Start-Process cmd '/c', (@'
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak
  echo hello
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak
'@ -split '\r?\n' -join ' & ')
```

The above uses:

- A verbatim [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) for the multi-line string.

  - **Important**: The closing here-string delimiter, `'@` in this case, must be _at the very start of a line - not even whitespace may precede it.
  - If you need string interpolation, use the *expandable* here-string variant, `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`
- [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)  `'\r?\n'` splits the multi-line string into individual lines...
- ... which [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)  `' & '` then joins together to form a single-line string in which the lines are concatenated with  `&` , as in your question.